# SeriLog Formatter: how to pass formatter parameters in the json configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, serilog

Is it possible to pass constructor parameters for Formatter in json config file?

```
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Console"
            "Args": { "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch" }
        }
     ]
```

As you can see here [ElasticsearchJsonFormatter](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch/blob/a9359d19b1b5371efa66d6deecda1fd00c541988/src/Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch/ElasticsearchJsonFormatter.cs#L76) ctor accepts some parameters. I would like to configure them in the config file above.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Comment: I had to create own `ElasticsearchJsonFormatter implementation. Took the source code and extended it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand the formatter, and explicitly specify type and all the parameters that need to be passed to the constructor:

```
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "formatter": {
        "type" : "Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter,Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch",
        "formatStackTraceAsArray" : true
      }
    }
  }
]
```